# How to save as list using multiple for-loops in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-itertools

I have two columns:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | David |
| 12 | Alex |
| 13 | Alice |
| 14 | Mark |
| 15 | Maria |

I would like to combine ID and Name together and save as a list. Eg, ['The ID 11 belongs to David']. How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
op=[]
for i, j in itertools.product(data['ID'], data['Name']):
        dt = str('The ID' + str(i)+ 'belongs to' +j)
        op.append(dt)
        print(dt)
```

The output is saved as a list multiple times. How do I correct that?

Desired output:

```
['The ID 11 belongs to David', 'The ID 12 belongs to Alex', 'The ID 13 belongs to Alice', 'The ID 14 belongs to Mark', 'The ID 15 belongs to Maria']
```

Comment: You are looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output is not a cross product of the lists `data['ID']` and `data['Name']`.

So do not use `itertools.product`, I think you want to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) instead. `zip(a, b)` returns a generator of tuples, matching up the first element of list `a` with the first element of list `b`, then the second elements of both lists, then the third, and so on.

You also could shorten your code to a list comprehension and use f-strings, making it more pythonic:

```
a = [13, 14, 15]
b = ["mark", "alice", "bob"]

result = [ f'ID {i} belongs to {j}' for i,j in zip(a,b) ]
print(result)
```

The output of that code would be:

```
['ID 13 belongs to mark', 'ID 14 belongs to alice', 'ID 15 belongs to bob']
```